# Clicking buttons in order allowing webpage to process between clicks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to automate my page test cases for the user to be able to press a button (update) from the Chrome extension and for each button matching the classes on the webpage I want to, one at a time, cycle them through:

1. Update: matching: `class="updateButton"`. Needs to be clicked once. Once clicked, the webpage will transition the button to the "save" state at some point.
2. Save: matching: `class="saveButton"`. Needs to be clicked once. Once clicked, the webpage will transition the button to the "saved" state at some point.
3. Saved: When the button gets here, we're done with this button.

After each button gets to the "saved" state, we can move on to the next button. I want to process all matching buttons through to the "saved" state.

I am very close. However, when I get the array length of `document.getElementsByClassName("saveButton")`, it keeps returning 1 which is weird. It should return 0 after the user has clicked save.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Chrome extension",
    "description": "My Chrome extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "https://mywebsite.com/*",
        "storage"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "30": "images/icons/30.png",
            "48": "images/icons/48.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icons/16.png",
        "20": "images/icons/20.png",
        "30": "images/icons/30.png",
        "48": "images/icons/48.png",
        "128": "images/icons/128.png"
    }
}
```

content_script.js:

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

function clickUpdate() {
    var updateArray = document.getElementsByClassName("updateButton");
    var updateArraySelector = document.querySelectorAll(".updateButton");
    var saveArray = document.getElementsByClassName("saveButton");
    var delay = 0;
    setSelectedValue(objSelect, "P");
    for (var a = 0; a < updateArraySelector.length; a++) {
        console.log("for loop started...")
        sleep(delay);
        console.log("this is the save array length after 1 second delay top: " + saveArray.length);
        //for each update button in the array do something..    
        //if the there is nothing in the saveArray 
        if (!saveArray.length) {
            updateArraySelector[a].click();
            sleep(delay);
            console.log("update clicked!" + a);
            for (var b = 0; b < saveArray.length; b++) {
                saveArray[b].click();
                sleep(delay);
            }
            sleep(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

popup.js

```js
//popup.js
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}
document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

popup.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>activity</title>

    <body>
        <button class="button button0" button id="clickactivity">Update</button>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is happening when you click save? Any XMLHttpRequests?

Comment: What if you introduce some delay? It is possible that the UI is not immediately updated.

Comment: @Deliaz When you click save the button changes to another button 'saved' and the class become 'saveDone'.

Comment: @xan I added the setTimeOut() delay but it is asynchronous and so it does act like a sleep.

Comment: Did you put `document.getElementsByClassName("saveButton");` into some small timeout?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Deliaz Yes, I added a sleep() function but it isn't updated the saveArray, until the after the for loop is done. I updated my code above.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour, please add the code as Makyen suggested.

Comment: @Makyen I updated the code and topic, please see if this is better.

Comment: @Deliaz Code has been updated. Please help check.

Comment: Do **not** use delay loops like your `sleep()`. Doing so breaks things. It doesn't allow other code to run during that time & loads down the CPU. Embrace the asynchronous nature of UI design (which is what JavaScript is all about). Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) for delays. [Yes, even though you have `delay = 0`, it's still bad to implement a delay like this, which will be between 0 to 1 ms.] You appear to be wanting the in-page code to do something. It won't be able to do so with `sleep()` (unless all is in it's `click` handler).

Comment: We are still going to need some example HTML against which you are running this code. We need enough information to be able to duplicate the problem. However, I would strongly suspect that your use of your `sleep()` function instead of `setTimeout()` is causing/contributing to the issue.

Comment: @Makyen My first approach was actually using the `setTimeout()` function, however, I noticed that this function is actually asynchronous and when I put the `setTimeout()` around the `saveArray[b].click()`, it would go through the remaining of the for loop first and then output the saveArraylength at the very end.. Unless I should placed it somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it's asynchronous, which is the point of using it. But, you need to use it to allow time for things to happen with processing in other scripts.

Comment: @Mayken I tried wrapping the `setTimeout()` function around the `if()` statement, but then it doesn't recognize my `.click()` function. Could you please show an example.

Comment: It's not clear to me: Are you wanting to click a single button through the "update"➞"save"➞"saved" transition, then move to the next button, or are you wanting to click all "update" buttons, then wait for some/all to change to "save" & click then wait some more and click some more, and only stop once all are clicked once in the "save" state. I'm assuming you want to click each button in each state only once.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, the former that you said is what I am trying to accomplish. "click a single button through the "update"➞"save"➞"saved" transition, then move to the next button". Keep going until the `updateArray.length` is 0 (reaches the end). The reason I have to do this, is because there are dependencies on the save button, there cannot be two save button present, if you try to do update multiple buttons at once, it will alert the user they need to finish the first set of steps before going on to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to have identified, the problem is in how your content script tries to loop on clicking the buttons.

A large portion of your problem is that you are using a delay, `sleep()` implemented in a straight loop. You should almost *never* do that in JavaScript. Doing it this way prevents other code from running. It will often result in things breaking and the CPU usage maxed-out.

The correct way to implement delays is asynchronously. A generic delay can be obtained using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). The point of which is that the delay needs to be asynchronous to allow other code to run in order for it to be able to accomplish the task you desire. If you are wanting to watch for changes in the DOM and be notified of changes, then you should use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead of `setTimeout()`.

### Implementing a `setTimeout()` loop

There are lots of ways that you could organize what you are doing. Below, I implement a `setTimeout()` loop, which is basically a function calling itself after a delay, if some condition is not met.

For this loop, the first thing we need is a function which will click the next button in sequence and return a `true` until such time as there are no more buttons which need clicking, at which time it returns `false`:

```js
function clickNextButton() {
    //This will click the next button in the sequence which we desire.
    //  A single button is moved from "update" (click) -> "save" (click) -> "saved".
    //  No other buttons are clicked until the first one we find is no longer in the
    //    "update" or "save" states.
    //  It returns false when there are no more buttons to click;
    //If there is a button in the "save" state, then we need to deal with it first and
    //  not move to the next "update" button until the "save" button changes to "saved".
    var firstSaveButton = document.querySelector('.saveButton');
    if(firstSaveButton) {
        let myFlagClass = 'myExtensionNameSaveClicked';
        if(firstSaveButton.classList.contains(myFlagClass)) {
            //We have already clicked this button. We need to wait for it to change state.
            return true; //There may be more to do.
        } //else
        firstSaveButton.classList.add(myFlagClass);
        firstSaveButton.click();
        return true; //There may be more to do.
    } //else
    //There is no button currently in the "save" state.
    //Check to see if there is a button in the "update" state.
    var firstUpdateButton = document.querySelector('.updateButton');
    if(firstUpdateButton) {
        let myFlagClass = 'myExtensionNameUpdateClicked';
        if(firstUpdateButton.classList.contains(myFlagClass)) {
            //We have already clicked this button. We need to wait for it to change state.
            return true; //There is more to do.
        } //else
        firstUpdateButton.classList.add(myFlagClass);
        firstUpdateButton.click();
        return true; //There is more to do.
    } //else
    //There are no buttons in the "update" or "save" state. We are done.
    return false;
}
```

#### Removing repeated code: iterate on button type

As you can see, there's considerable repetition in the code. We can rearrange it so we just run the same code while just changing the type of button we're looking for.

The following uses [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which loops through an array until the first time the called function returns `true`. It's a good way to loop through an array until some condition is met and then not be called for the rest of the elements. This is used to deal with any buttons in the `"save"` state prior to considering ones in the `"update"` state.

```js
function clickNextButton() {
    //This will click the next button in the sequence which we desire.
    //  A single button is moved from "update" (click) -> "save" (click) -> "saved".
    //  No other buttons are clicked until the first one we find is no longer in the
    //    "update" or "save" states.
    //  It returns false when there are no more buttons to click;
    //If there is a button in the "save" state, then we need to deal with it first and
    //  not move to the next "update" button until the "save" button changes to "saved".
    return ['save','update'].some(function(type) {
        var firstButton = document.querySelector('.' + type + 'Button');
        if(firstButton) {
            let myFlagClass = 'myExtensionName' + type + 'Clicked';
            if(firstButton.classList.contains(myFlagClass)) {
                //We've already clicked this button; need to wait for it to change state.
                return true; //There may be more to do.
            } //else
            firstButton.classList.add(myFlagClass);
            firstButton.click();
            return true; //There may be more to do.
        } //else
        return false; //No buttons of this type exist.
    });
}
```

We now have code that will click the next button and will tell us if there are no more buttons to click. So, we just need a loop that keeps calling that function until there are no more buttons to click. We want a delay between each time we call it. There a few different ways which you could wait for changes in the DOM. Using a [MutationObserer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) allows you to actually wait for changes in the DOM. In this case, given that we do not need to know *immediately* when the state changes, and our check for the changing state can be reasonably low cost (a couple of DOM walks), we can just use a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) loop to check every so often.

#### The actual `setTimeout()` loop

In the following code, I chose to check for changes in the buttons every 200ms. From what you described, you *don't* need to check any more often than that. If you *really* want to, you might reduce that to 100ms, if you have a *large* number of buttons (hundreds) that you are needing to click (i.e. where reducing the time between checks would save some significant amount of time).

That can do a `setTimeout()` loop for this like [Note: To make the basic `setTimeout()` loop more clear, this does not contain some clean-up code executed when we are done. That code is added in the snippet below.]:

```js
function clickMoreButtons() {
    if(clickNextButton()){
        //Keep clicking buttons until there are none in the "update" or "save" states.
        setTimeout(clickMoreButtons,200); //Call this function again in 200ms.
    }
}
```

### Putting it all together with some code to show whats happening

The following snippet puts all the code together. It adds a bit of code to clean up the classes which are used as flags to indicate a button has been clicked. In addition, there is some code to simulate what the webpage is doing with changing the state of the buttons.

As part of the clean-up code, [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is used to convert the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) to an Array. These elements are then iterated over to remove the classes we use as flags. This could be a bit more optimized. It could take advantage of the fact that `myExtensionNameupdateClicked` should never be on an element without also having a `myExtensionNameSaveClicked`. However, it doesn't cost that much to not optimize here and makes it such that if the operation of the page changes to go directly from "update" to "saved", we don't miss some elements. You could use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll) here to get all of both classes, but `querySelectorAll()` is about 10x slower than `getElementsByClassName()`, so it's actually not an optimization.

The CSS, HTML and JavaScript in the HTML block are just code used to simulate what's happening in the webpage. Only the code in the JavaScript clock should be considered for your content script.

```js
function clickNextButton() {
    //This will click the next button in the sequence which we desire.
    //  A single button is moved from "update" (click) -> "save" (click) -> "saved".
    //  No other buttons are clicked until the first one we find is no longer in the
    //    "update" or "save" states.
    //  It returns false when there are no more buttons to click;
    //If there is a button in the "save" state, then we need to deal with it first and
    //  not move to the next "update" button until the "save" button changes to "saved".
    return ['save','update'].some(function(type) {
        var firstButton = document.querySelector('.' + type + 'Button');
        if(firstButton) {
            let myFlagClass = 'myExtensionName' + type + 'Clicked';
            if(firstButton.classList.contains(myFlagClass)) {
                //We've already clicked this button;
                //  need to wait for it to change state.
                return true; //There may be more to do.
            } //else
            firstButton.classList.add(myFlagClass);
            firstButton.click();
            return true; //There may be more to do.
        } //else
        return false; //No buttons of this type exist.
    });
}

function clickMoreButtons() {
    if(clickNextButton()) {
        //Keep clicking buttons until there are none in the "update" or "save" states.
        setTimeout(clickMoreButtons,200); //Call this function again in 200ms.
    } else {
        //Clean up the classes we used as flags.
        let flagClasses=['myExtensionNameupdateClicked','myExtensionNamesaveClicked'];
        //For all flag classes:
        flagClasses.forEach(function(flagClass){
            //Get the list of elements with that class, convert it to an Array, then
            //  iterate through each, removing the class.
            [...document.getElementsByClassName(flagClass)].forEach(function(element) {
                element.classList.remove(flagClass);
            });
         });
        console.log('All done');
    }
}

clickMoreButtons();
```

```css
.updateButton {
    background: orange;
}
.saveButton {
    background: lightblue;
}
.savedButton {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button class="updateButton">update</button> <button class="updateButton">update</button>
<button class="updateButton">update</button> <button class="updateButton">update</button>
<button class="updateButton">update</button> <button class="updateButton">update</button>
<script>
    function updateButtonState(button){
        timer=0; //Clear the record of the timer
        ['saved','save','update'].some(function(type,index,array) {
            var checkClass = type + 'Button';
            if(button.classList.contains(checkClass)) {
                if(index === 0) {
                    return true; //stop
                }
                let newType = array[index-1];
                let newClass = newType + 'Button';
                button.classList.remove(checkClass);
                button.classList.add(newClass);
                button.textContent = newType;
                return true; //stop
            } //else
            return false; //Not this type of button
        });
    }
    var timer=0;
    document.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
        if(event.target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON') {
            return;
        }
        if(!timer) {
            //Don't permit more than one to be in process at a time.
            //Wait 1 second to change the class to simulate the asynchronous nature of
            //  the process.
            timer = setTimeout(updateButtonState,1000,event.target);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, i am amazed by the detailed explanation, let me read through this and will ask questions if I don't understand anything. Thank you :)